# Are the (133,885) molecules in the QM9 database drug-like?

Tags: computational-chemistry, drugs

Are all the individual 133,845 molecules of QM9 drug-like molecules?
Can other drug-like molecules be made from the these 133,845 molecules by some combination or permutation which are not part of QM9?

Comment: How would you propose the drug-like properties are checked?

Comment: @Waylander, by using RDKit and Frechet distance could be a good starting point...

Comment: @Waylander, I have made the edit to my question, I wanted to know are all the individual molecules in QM9 are drug candidates, I mean is every molecule is a complete in itself or do we need to combine different molecules of QM9 to find a effective drug ?

Comment: I have not worked with QM9 but similar packages I have worked with consisted of fragments which would need to be extended to improve activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QM9 contains a subset (with up to nine non-hydrogen atoms CNOF) of the GDB-17 database (up to 17 non-hydrogen atoms CNOS and halogen). Here is what the authors of GDB-17 said about drug-like:

> While GDB-11 and GDB-13 uncovered impressive numbers of possible molecules, the databases only addressed very small organic molecules (MW < 200 Da), which are of interest as relatively small fragments but rarely correspond to actual drugs. Herein we report the enumeration of organic molecules up to 17 atoms of C, N, O, S, and halogens, forming the chemical universe database GDB-17 containing 166.4 billion organic molecules. GDB-17 reaches into molecular sizes compatible with many drugs (367 approved drugs ≤17 atoms) and typical for lead compounds (100 < MW < 350 Da). Millions of isomers of known drugs are readily identified in GDB-17.
>
> [...] The idea is to enumerate molecules from first principles starting from mathematical graphs irrespective of pre-existing building blocks to avoid a historical bias in structure selection. Geometrical strain and functional group stability criteria are used to ensure that the molecules produced are chemically meaningful.
>
> [...]While molecules up to 17 atoms in the public databases PubChem, ChEMBL, or DrugBrank are mostly achiral, aromatic, and heteroaromatic compounds with rodlike shapes, GDB-17 molecules are mostly nonaromatic heterocycles with many quaternary centers and stereoisomers.
>
> Source: doi.org/10.1021/ci300415d

This seems to answer the OP's questions:

> [OP] Are all the individual 133,845 molecules of QM9 drug-like molecules?

No, probably not a single one because they are too small.

> [OP] Can other drug-like molecules also be made from the these 133,845 molecules by some combination or permutation which are not part of QM9?

Yes, by combining them in a reasonable way, you would get larger molecules (see Waylander's comment to the question). You would also have to check a parameter related to solubility. The computed data in QM9 would probably be helpful:

> We report computed geometric, energetic, electronic, and thermodynamic properties for 134k stable small organic molecules made up of CHONF. These molecules correspond to the subset of all 133,885 species with up to nine heavy atoms (CONF) out of the GDB-17 chemical universe of 166 billion organic molecules. We report geometries minimal in energy, corresponding harmonic frequencies, dipole moments, polarizabilities, along with energies, enthalpies, and free energies of atomization.
>
> [...]
> This data set contains small amino acids, such as GLY, ALA, as well as nucleobases cytosine, uracil, and thymine. Also pharmaceutically relevant organic building blocks, such as pyruvic acid, piperazine, or hydroxy urea are included.
>
> Source: https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201422

Answer (score 6):

No. The molecules in QM9 (i.e., a subset of the [GDB-11](https://gdb.unibe.ch/downloads/)) are part of an enumeration of possible compounds.

> GDB-11 enumerates small organic molecules up to 11 atoms of C, N, O and F following simple chemical stability and synthetic feasibility rules.

The enumeration process is covered in the paper by the Reymond group:

[Virtual Exploration of the Chemical Universe up to 11 Atoms of C, N, O, F](https://doi.org/10.1021/ci600423u)

My understanding from the von Lilienfeld group, is that the full GDB-11 (26.4 million structures) was too big. So they scaled back to up to 9 "heavy atoms" of C, N, O, F, which was a more reasonable number of DFT optimizations.

Almost none of these are "drug-like" by the usual rules (e.g., [Lipinski Rule-of-Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipinski%27s_rule_of_five)).